# jQuery remove options from select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add the same select box multiple times with jQuery.
Here's the code I'm trying:

```
$(".add").on("click", function(){ 
    $select_box = '<div><select><option value="v1">Value 1</option><option value="v2">Value 2</option><option value="v3">Value 3</option></select></div>';

 $('.box').append($select_box);

});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/hC578/

The above code works fine. However, I want to check if an option value has been selected in any of the previous select box, it should not appear in the later select boxes.

For example, if option 1 is selected in the first select box, and another select box is added, it should not list the option 1 in it.

How this can be done?

Comment: u need logic or code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

**html**

```
<div class="box">


</div>

<button class="add">Add</button>
```

**js**

```
$(".add").on("click", function(){ 
    $select_box = '<div><select><option value="v1">Value 1</option><option value="v2">Value 2</option><option value="v3">Value 3</option></select></div>';
var ddl = $($select_box).children();

    var a= $("select").val();


    if(a!="")
        $("option[value='" + a + "']").remove();

 $('.box').append($select_box);


});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hC578/23/)

Ok i change a bit, try this version please:

**js**

```
$(".add").on("click", function(){ 
    $select_box = '<div><select><option value="v1">Value 1</option><option value="v2">Value 2</option><option value="v3">Value 3</option></select></div>';
var ddl = $($select_box).children();

    var a= new Array();
    var i=0;
    $("select").each(function(){               
        a[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
    });

    if(a.length>0){
        for(var j=0; j<a.length; j++){
            $(ddl).find("option[value='"+a[j]+"']").remove();
        }
    }

 $('.box').append(ddl);


});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hC578/53/)

For your last request:

**js**

```
$(".add").on("click", function(){ 
    $select_box = '<div><select onchange="ddlChange(this);"><option value="v1">Value 1</option><option value="v2">Value 2</option><option value="v3">Value 3</option></select></div>';
var ddl = $($select_box).children();

    var a= new Array();
    var i=0;
    $("select").each(function(){               
        a[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
    });

    if(a.length>0){
        for(var j=0; j<a.length; j++){
            $(ddl).find("option[value='"+a[j]+"']").remove();
        }
    }

 $('.box').append(ddl);


});

window.ddlChange = function(ddl){

    var a= new Array();
    var i=0;
    $("select").each(function(){               
        a[i] = $(this).val();
        i++;
    });

    if(a.length>1){
        for(var j=0; j<a.length; j++){
            $(ddl).find("option[value='"+a[j]+"']").remove();
        }
    }

 $('.box').append(ddl);


};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hC578/71/)

Comment: Thanks but this does opposite. When you select an option in the second select, it removes from the first select box and reset its value.

Comment: Can you try my last change please?

Comment: Thanks, it works. However once we have added the select boxes and we change the select option in one of it, then it is possible to have same option in 2 or more boxes. Is it possible to remove the options from other select boxes after the value has been changed in any of the select box? Thanks anyway, I've +1 your answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to change the way you generate your options. They would need to come from an object and on that object you will be able to store the value, label but also if it was previously selected.

Something like this, an array which stored your options.

```
var options = [
    {label: "a", value: "A", selected: null},
    {label: "a", value: "A", selected: null},
    {label: "a", value: "A", selected: null},
];
```

So then you can loop over them when creating the list of options.

```
var options_html = "";

options.forEach(function(option) {
    // only use if selected is null
    if (option.selected === null) {
        options_html += "<option value='"+option.value+"'>"+option.label+"</option>";
    }
});
```

When an option is selected just go over the options array, find it and mark it as selected.

Comment: Well no, in that link you are redefining the options array every time which of course reset the selected value. Also I provided you with the logic not the all code. You need another bit of code to actually updated the selected property. I'll update your demo.

Comment: Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Epkx3/1/ Also it should be cleaned up as you probably want to have the option html generation and the selection logic in separate functions. But that's more moving on to which architecture you should use more than anything.

Answer (score 1):

Build the options from an array instead of a hard-coded HTML string. When one of the options is selected previously, pop the corresponding item out of the array so that it is not present when the new selects are built from the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".add").on("click", function () {
    var box = $('.box');

    // append new one
    box.append('<div><select><option value="v1">Value 1</option><option value="v2">Value 2</option><option value="v3">Value 3</option></select></div>');

    // remove others with selected option
    $('option[selected="selected"]', box).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code.
have an array of all dropdown items.
Find elements selected in added dropdowns.
Add only those.

```
$(document).on("click",".add", function(){ 
    var options=[
        {label:"1",value:"1"},
        {label:"2",value:"2"},
        {label:"3",value:"3"}
    ];
    var selectedVal=[];
    $("select.dropdown").each(function(){
        selectedVal.push($(this).val());
    });
    options=$.grep( options, function( val, i ) {
        return $.inArray(val.value,selectedVal)==-1;
    });
    var dropdown="<select class='dropdown'>";
    options.forEach(function(ele){
        dropdown+="<option value='"+ele.value+"'>"+ele.label+"</option>";
    });
    dropdown+="</select>";
    $(".box").append(dropdown);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I tried, it does not work. Can you update the demo on jsfiddle?